# Basic Ruby On Rails Linking Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am beginning to work with Rails and I get some of the concepts but am stuck on an important one.

Let's say I have customers which has many jobs and jobs which belongs to customers.

How would I go about creating a new job for a customer?

I can create a link that goes to customers/1/jobs/new and I can grab the customer ID but how do I tell it that I am creating a job for customer 1?

I know this is the most basic of things but I just need a push in the right direction.

This is my form so far:
How do I get :customer_id to populate with the customer_id param?

```
    <h1>New job</h1>

<% form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :customer_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :customer_id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :manufacturer %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :manufacturer %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :serial_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :serial_number %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :problem %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :problem %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :notes %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :notes %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :tech_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tech_id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', jobs_path %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `form_for([@customer, @job])`, this should generate the correct URLs (`/customers/:customer_id/jobs` etc).

You can then fetch `params[:customer_id]` in your `JobsController.create` method.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!  I need to find a good solid tutorial, ROR is such a paradigm shift for me but I do find it fun to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long, maintained, descriptive list of good [ruby programming tutorials](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/3398/ruby-programming-tutorial). Good luck.